# Unable to start up Pax-web

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, pax-web

I'm playing with OSGi via the framework implementation Felix 5.4. Currently I want to install an application server on a OSGi framework as a bundle. I've look at Pax-web and it seems the perfect solution for me.
However, after successfully started up all the required bundles, The software complains with the following error:

```
org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty-bundle[org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.Activator] : Unable to start pax web server: Exception while starting Jetty
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while starting Jetty
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl.start(JettyServerImpl.java:188)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl$Stopped.start(ServerControllerImpl.java:415)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl.start(ServerControllerImpl.java:71)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl$Unconfigured.configure(ServerControllerImpl.java:707)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.ServerControllerImpl.configure(ServerControllerImpl.java:87)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.Activator.updateController(Activator.java:353)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.Activator$3.run(Activator.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl.start(JettyServerImpl.java:151)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration.setMaxErrorDispatches(class java.lang.String)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:815)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
        ... 16 more
```

By looking at the error, it seems that some Jetty configurations are not available in the pax-embedded jetty version. In particular `maxErrorDispatches`, `blockingTimeout` and `persistentConnectionsEnabled` causes the error. However, even commenting out those 3 properties, pax-web won't start (can't connect to 127.0.0.1) and, after some logs, will simply print:

> org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty-bundle[org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.ConfigurationImpl]
>   : Reading configuration property org.ops4j.pax.web.config.url has
>   failed

I've tried to solve this issue, but since I'm no expert in neither OSGi and Jetty I couldn't come up with no solution. To add some context to my scenario, here's some additional information:

- I'm using felix 5.4;
- I'm using Windows 10 64-bit;
- jetty.xml i in the same directory of conf/, bin/ felix folder;
- The launching felix via `java -jar bin\felix.jar`

**Bundles installed:**

```
lb
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (5.6.0)|5.6.0
    1|Active     |    1|ASM (5.1.0)|5.1.0
    2|Active     |    1|ASM commons classes (5.1.0)|5.1.0
    3|Active     |    1|ASM Tree class visitor (5.1.0)|5.1.0
    4|Active     |    1|javax.servlet API v.3.0 (3.0.0.SNAPSHOT)|3.0.0.SNAPSHOT
    5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (2.0.8)|2.0.8
    6|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.16.0)|0.16.0
    7|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.16.2)|0.16.2
    8|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)|0.10.0
    9|Active     |    1|osgi (3.0.0)|3.0.0
   10|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Logging - API (1.9.0)|1.9.0
   11|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Web - API (4.3.0)|4.3.0
   12|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Web - Extender - WAR (4.3.0)|4.3.0
   13|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Web - Jetty Bundle (4.3.0)|4.3.0
   14|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Web - Jsp Support (4.3.0)|4.3.0
   15|Active     |    1|OPS4J Pax Web - Service SPI (4.3.0)|4.3.0
   16|Active     |    1|Apache XBean OSGI Bundle Utilities (4.5.0)|4.5.0
   17|Active     |    1|Apache XBean :: Classpath Resource Finder (4.5.0)|4.5.0
```

**config.properties (stripped from comments):**

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=org.apache.juli.logging

org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=sun.*,com.sun.*

org.osgi.framework.storage.clean=onFirstInit

felix.auto.deploy.action=install,start

felix.auto.deploy.dir=pax

felix.log.level=1

org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning=1

felix.startlevel.bundle=1

org.osgi.service.http.port=8080
obr.repository.url=http://felix.apache.org/obr/releases.xml

org.ops4j.pax.web.config.file=jetty.xml
```

**Jetty configuration (without comments):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <Get name="ThreadPool">
      <Set name="minThreads" type="int"><Property name="jetty.threadPool.minThreads" deprecated="threads.min" default="10"/></Set>
      <Set name="maxThreads" type="int"><Property name="jetty.threadPool.maxThreads" deprecated="threads.max" default="200"/></Set>
      <Set name="idleTimeout" type="int"><Property name="jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout" deprecated="threads.timeout" default="60000"/></Set>
      <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
    </Get>

    <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler"/>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
      <Set name="secureScheme"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme" default="https" /></Set>
      <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.securePort" deprecated="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
      <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputBufferSize" deprecated="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
      <Set name="outputAggregationSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize" deprecated="jetty.output.aggregation.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion" deprecated="jetty.send.server.version" default="true" /></Set>
      <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendDateHeader" deprecated="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
      <Set name="headerCacheSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize" default="512" /></Set>
      <Set name="delayDispatchUntilContent"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.delayDispatchUntilContent" deprecated="jetty.delayDispatchUntilContent" default="true"/></Set>
      <Set name="maxErrorDispatches"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.maxErrorDispatches" default="10"/></Set>
      <Set name="blockingTimeout"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.blockingTimeout" default="-1"/></Set>
      <Set name="persistentConnectionsEnabled"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.persistentConnectionsEnabled" default="true"/></Set>
    </New>

    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
         <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
           <Item>
             <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
           </Item>
         </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <Set name="stopAtShutdown"><Property name="jetty.server.stopAtShutdown" default="true"/></Set>
    <Set name="stopTimeout"><Property name="jetty.server.stopTimeout" default="5000"/></Set>
    <Set name="dumpAfterStart"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpAfterStart" deprecated="jetty.dump.start" default="false"/></Set>
    <Set name="dumpBeforeStop"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop" deprecated="jetty.dump.stop" default="false"/></Set>

</Configure>
```

Comment: Which jetty version do you use? Your list of bundles does not show jetty.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider: right now I'm using "pax-web-jetty-bundle", version 4.3.0. By looking inside the jar, I found Jetty is embedded within it: the manifest of said bundle contains an Export-Package entry saying:  org.eclipse.jetty;version="9.2.19.v20160908". I deduce I'm using 9.2 jetty version; am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your jetty version seems to match the pax web version. So this should not be the problem.

I just tested pax web in Apache karaf 4.0.7. There pax-web 4.3.0 and jetty 9.2.1 are used too. Karaf uses the individual jetty bundles though.

So I suspect there is an error in the pax-web-jetty-bundle. Can you open a jira issue at ops4j for this?

To fix your problem now you should install the same bundles that Apache karaf uses. Download and start karaf 4.0.7 and do feature:install http.

Then check the bundles using la -u. If you use the same bundles then it should work for you too.